# How to programmatically add a second view in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to switch to a second view from a button on the first view, and do this programmatically (not using the traditional way of switching between views using a segue on the storyboard)

My current app delegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
public class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    public var window: UIWindow?

    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())

        return true
    }
```

Button function in first view controller that when pressed should just switch to new view:

```
func signupAction (sender: UIButton!){

}
```

I already have the new viewcontroller file created:

```
class Signup: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to achieve the button in the first viewcontroller transitions to this signup viewcontroller.

Comment: So you want to add a second view CONTROLLER? Do not say view when you mean view controller. The terms mean something different, and when you say you want to add a second view it makes it sound like you want to add a subview, not a new view controller.

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller and want to push a new view controller on the navigation stack? Do you want to present your new view controller modally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a `UINavigationController` you could push the `Signup` view controller to the navigation stack this way:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let signUpViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signUpViewController") as! Signup
navigationController?.pushViewController(signUpViewController, animated: true)
```

If you are not in `UINavigationController` and want to present it, you can do it this way:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let signUpViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signUpViewController") as! Signup
self.present(signUpViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Note: Don't forget to set the identifier of your view controller in the storyboard.

Comment: Im trying not to use the storyboard at all, but i figured out that i need to push it through the navigation controller