# How to call a a different view by code in xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode7

I am new to xcode 7 and it would be great if you could help me with something.

I have two ViewControllers and I would like to call ViewController2 from ViewController1. I need to do that by code. (I would like to call it from the viewDidLoad()-function)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically add a second view in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000264/how-to-programmatically-add-a-second-view-in-swift-3)

Comment: if you are using storyboard, you will to set & get the storyboard id, then `let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "id") as? ViewController2`  then you `present it self.present(vc,animted:true, completion: nil)` if you are not using storyboard just `present(ViewController2(),animated:true, completion:nil)`

Comment: We need more information than you have provided. Are both view controllers active, i.e. have they been presented already? Are you using segues?

Comment: Thanks! I am not using segues and only the first controller is active

Comment: @Lamar I set th storyboard ID of ViewController2 and pasted this in the viewDidLoad()-Function of ViewController1: let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myIDOfViewController2") as? ViewController2    Now the editor underlines <"withIdentifier: "myIDOfViewController2"> and says "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you have the project and your navigation setup, here is one of the many ways to accomplish what I think you are asking.

If you are using Segues for navigation, in the ViewController1 (That initialized the navigation) you would override the prepareForSegue function cast your segue.destination as ViewController2 and set the property. Like this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    guard let viewController2 = segue.destination as? ViewController2 else { return }

    viewController2.propertyName = "Property Value"
}
```

Or, if you are wanting to instantiate `ViewController2` in `ViewController1` you could do this:

```
override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let viewController2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ID for ViewController (set in the Storyboard)") as? ViewController2 else { return }
    viewController2.propertyName = "Property Value"

    self.present(viewController2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    // Or you could do if you want a full navigation, not just a modal.
    self.show(viewController2, sender: self)
}
```

If you are wanting to access each view controller, you could do something like this:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    weak var viewController1: ViewController1? //The 'weak' keyword is incredibly important so that you don't have a memory leak.

    override viewDidLoad() {
        self.viewController1.propertyName = "Property Value"
    }
}
```

Using the same steps as above, you can set the `viewController1` property in the `ViewController2` instance.

Now I hope that answers your question. Your question is a little vague, so I am shooting in the dark.

Comment: I am not using segues for navigation because I need to switch a lot between 8 Views. Everything my app has to do is Checking the battery-status and depending on the status switch in one of the views. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: And then it starts all over again. So if I was using segues it would get quite complicated

Comment: So did my answer work for you? Or what part do you need help with?

Comment: I tried to implement your second code-block. The editor is underlining "instantiateViewController" and says "Value of UIStoryboard has no memberínstantiateViewController`"

Comment: andy idea how to fix that?

Comment: I accidentally had the 'i' uppercased. Try it lowercase. The auto code complete should have the correct function name if you start to type it out.

Comment: there is only instantiateInitialViewController or instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. So it is the second one?

Comment: so should it be like this? instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("my setup storyboardID")?

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, I just noticed you said Xcode 7 (The latest is Xcode 8), which means you're using an older version of Swift (Most likely Swift 2). My answer is in Swift 3. So yeah, instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("my setup storyboardID") should work in Swift 2. Sorry, Swift 3 made name convention changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot so far for your help! But now I have another problem. For the following there lines of code it says that the type has no member "property Name" and "present"

Comment: Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149422/discussion-between-beardy-bear-and-seanrobinson159).